# Redux state updated but component not re-rendered (while using promise)

Tags: reactjs, redux, promise

I am using React/Redux.
The main issue is that when i use Promise then component is not re-rendered, whereas the code is working fine when promise code is not used.

**Action Creator**

```
    const updateColor = colorobj => {
      return dispatch => 
      new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        dispatch(fetchColorBegin());
        axios
          .post(config.APIURL.color.update, colorobj)
          .then(response => {
            const data = response.data;
            if (data.errorno !== 0) {
              dispatch(fetchColorFailure(data.errormsg));
              reject(data.errormsg);
            } else {
              dispatch(updateColorSuccess(colorobj));
              resolve('Color Updated');
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            dispatch(fetchColorFailure(error.message));
            reject(error.message);
          });
      });
    };
```

**Reducer**

```
 case UPDATE_COLOR_SUCCESS:
      const todoIndex = state.data.findIndex(todo => todo.id === action.payload.id);
      return update(state, {
        loading: { $set: false },
        data: { [todoIndex]: { $merge: action.payload } },
        error: { $set: null}
      });
```

**Component**
the state is updated but the component is not updated.

```
const handleEditOk = values => {
    let colorobj = {
      id: state.updateData.id,
      colorname: values.colorname,
      colorcode: values.colorcode,
    };
    dispatch(updateColor(colorobj))
      .then(response => {
        message.success(response);
        onCancel();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        message.error(error);
      });
  };
```

The component update itself only on commenting the promise code.
The problem now is that it is not showing success/failure message.

```
  const handleEditOk = values => {
    let colorobj = {
      id: state.updateData.id,
      colorname: values.colorname,
      colorcode: values.colorcode,
    };
    dispatch(updateColor(colorobj))
      // .then(response => {
      //   message.success(response);
      //   onCancel();
      // })
      // .catch(error => {
      //   message.error(error);
      // });
  };
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Remove the Promise constructor from the action creator. Action creator just needs to return a function which it already is but the Promise constructor is not needed.

Comment: Actually I have opened a Modal Window to edit the record, and need to close the modal in case of success only. I thought it would be possible while using promise.
I tried it this way as suggested https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/returning-promises-from-redux-action-creators-3035f34fa74b
In case i won't use Promise, then what would be the alternate to check the case of success/failure in component.

Comment: Returning a promise from the function that is returned by the action creator does not make it a return value of the `dispatch` function; use the state to determine whether your request was successful or not.

Comment: Can you suggest some code

Comment: Can you create a minimal, reproducible demo on codesandbox and share the link?